# SQL SSRS Report Manager site asking to login every time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

SQL Server 2012 / SSRS. Windows 2008 R2. When trying to access the Report Manager via URL (http://servername/reports), it prompts us for a username and password. When I enter a valid user/pass it works and I can get to the Report Manager site and run reports fine. But we don't want to be prompted, we don't even need Windows Authentication, just to go strait in to the page. Any ideas why its asking for a username and password and how I can allow direct access?

Comment: What browser do you use? You should use IE, even if Chrome support was announced, Chrome has problems like this

Comment: I've tried with IE, Firefox and Chrome. I remember having this exact same problem years ago and can't remember what the heck solved it. It sucks!

Comment: I just want anybody (intranet or internet) to be able to access it. No user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the credentials in the report.

> You can store the credentials used to access an external data source.
> Credentials are stored in reversible encryption in the report server
> database. You can specify one set of stored credentials for each data
> source used in a report. The credentials you provide retrieve the same
> data for every user who runs the report.
>
> Stored credentials are
> recommended as part of a strategy for accessing remote database
> servers. Stored credentials are required if you want to support
> subscriptions, or schedule report history generation or report
> snapshot refreshes. When a report runs as a background process, the
> report server is the agent that executes the report. Because there is
> no user context in place, the report server must get credential
> information from the report server database in order to connect to a
> data source. The user name and password that you specify can be
> Windows credentials or a database login. If you specify Windows
> credentials, the report server passes the credentials to Windows for
> subsequent authentication. Otherwise, the credentials are passed to
> the database server for authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/specify-credential-and-connection-information-for-report-data-sources

Comment: When trying to access the Report Manager via URL (http://servername/reports), it prompts us for a username and password.

Comment: Sometimes I wish there was a comment downvote button.

Comment: Downvoting as this is failing to address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure Windows AD and set up NTLM/Kerberos in SSRS. This would help to seamlessly access the resources without an username and password.

Comment: I've enabled NTLM in the RSReportServer.config file. Can't I just use a local service account or something like just allow all users, anonymous?

Comment: No, SSRS doesn't support Anonymous authentication. You could configure Kerberos or NTLM for a set of users in a network and use the reports from that network. It wouldn't prompt you for an username or password